# Relationship mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a two table `Company` and `CompanyRepo` like below

`COMAPNY`

[image]

`COMPANY_REPO`

[image]

I have `entities` for those two tables like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COMAPNY")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="COMPANY_ID")
    private Long companyId;

    @Column
    private String companyName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="COMPANY")
    private List<CompanyRepo> companyRepo;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="COMAPNY_REPO")
public class CompanyRepo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="COMPANY_REPO_ID")
    private Long companyRepoId;

    @Column
    private String COMPANY_ID;

    @Column
    private String DEPT_ID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")
    private Company company;
}
```

Now i want to execute below query using a Hibernate relationship mapping

```
select Company_name from company as C ,company_repo as cr where c.company_id=cr.company_id and dept_id=10
```

I wrote a JPA repository like below by using a `@OneToMany` in `Company` table and `@ManyToOne` in `CompanyRepo`. But in resultant I am getting multiple `COMPANY`object inside `COMPANY_REPO` Object.Does my relationship mapping is correct ?

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<CompanyRepo, Long> {

    public CompanyRepo findByDeptId(Long deptId);

}
```

Comment: To clarify, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with your query? Are you wanting to retrieve a `Company` given a department id? If so, is it possible for (through the company repo table), a single department to be associated with multiple companies?

Answer (score 0):

Given your current database design, try something such as the following:

```
    public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {

        @Query(value="SELECT * from company as C WHERE c.company_id = (SELECT cr.company_id FROM company_repo as cr WHERE cr.dept_id = ?1)", nativeQuery=true)
        public Company findByDeptId(Long deptId);

    }
```

The `@Query` annotation is a very powerful and flexible way to define methods in Repository interface. If you need more complex logic,  I would recommend reading about the use and possibilities of the annotation. See [here.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand. I certainly could have made an obvious mistake, but have you tried it? If so, what error did you receive?

Comment: It sounds as if Spring is ignoring the annotation and just trying to use the method name to build the database. Did you add the Query annotation and import `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`? If so, try renaming `findByDeptID` to something else. It can be almost anything; just want to force the app to use `@Query` and not the method name.

Comment: That was my mistake. I thought you were column name was `department_id` not `dept_id`. Try changing `cr.department_id` to `cr.dept_id` in the code above. I would also advise annotating the `COMPANY_ID` property in CompanyRepo with `@Column(name="DEPT_ID")`.

Comment: If by mappings, you mean the annotations in the entity class, then, in general,  yes, you still need mappings even with `nativeQuery`. Using `nativeQuery`  impacts how repository queries the database to retrieve the data needed to populate the objects. Specifying nativeQuery was probably not strictly necessary in this case, but I think it made for a cleaner query string and code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your entity class your have multiple
`COMPANY_ID` that is not a proper way to declare your column name.

1. `@Column
   private String COMPANY_ID;`
2. `@ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")
   private Company company;`

So please change your `@Column
    private String COMPANY_ID;` to `@Column("comp_id)
    private String companyId;`

If you want to get the CompanyRepo based on `Company` type then you need to change your query to fetch the dept id.

And your `@Column
    private String DEPT_ID;` is String datatype so pass String to your repository.

```
@Query(" select companyRepo.company from CompanyRepo as companyRepo where companyRepo.DEPT_ID = :deptId")
    public Company findByDeptId(String deptId);
```